# How to encode correctly a text extracted from a pdf with python?

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, pypdf

I'm trying to extract the content of a pdf using `pypdf2`. But the result is not well encoded. For example: the 'e' and 'a' are replaced by some other symbol. I want the result of the extract to be encoded correctly in utf-8, the language of the pdf is french. the code that I used to start my work can be found at this link : https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-extract-text-from-pdf-in-python/

thank you all for your help guys.

I've already tried to use the encode and decode but without succes, ( I may have used them uncorrectly),

```
# Open the pdf file in read binary mode.
fileObject = open(filePath, 'rb')

# Create a pdf reader .
pdfFileReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(fileObject, strict=False)

# Get total pdf page number.
totalPageNumber = pdfFileReader.numPages

currentPageNumber = 0
text = ''

while(currentPageNumber < 3 ):

    # Get the specified pdf page object.
    pdfPage = pdfFileReader.getPage(currentPageNumber)

    # Get pdf page text.
    text = text + pdfPage.extractText()
    text.encode('utf-8',"ignore")


    # Process next page.
    currentPageNumber += 1

pdfText = text
```

here is the output I'm getting:

```
Fr@nceElectricPage 1/12Aspectsde la norme NF C15-100D•apr†s l•auteur, la norme NF 15-100 fixe la r‡glementation des installations ‡lectriques. Elle est r‡guli†rement remise … jour pour prendre
```

the output I want:

```
FranceElectricPage 1/12Aspectsde la norme NF C15-100D•après l'auteur, la norme NF 15-100 fixe la réglementation des installations électriques. Elle est réguliérement remise … jour pour prendre
```

Comment: Have you tried another encoding, like Latin-1?

Comment: yes I've tried it, it is not working too, I don't think it is from the type

Comment: Have you tried to open the properties of your pdf, whith adobe reader for example? You should be able to get the encoding there

Comment: And also, if you are on linux or mac, `cat your_output.txt | od -c` might help to see what are those special characters exactly.

Comment: no I haven't try with adobe acrobate reader I'll try it.

Comment: there is no useful information in the adobe acrobate reader properties section